After adding custom password validator lockoutOnFailure stopped working in ASP.NET Identity
I have several settings related to password complexity, and their values can change dynamically from another server. To handle this, I implemented a custom password validator that reads the settings from the database and validates passwords accordingly.
This is my ApplicationPasswordValidator.
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
    .AddUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>()
    .AddRoleStore<ApplicationRoleStore>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddSignInManager<ApplicationSignInManager>()
    .AddTokenProvider<CustomDataProtectorTokenProvider>("CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider")
    .AddPasswordValidator<ApplicationPasswordValidator>();

But after this, in my login function, the lockout on failure stopped working, even after multiple wrong password entries:
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password,
                model.SelectedTenant, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

But if I remove the line below, account lockout is working again, but password validation is not happening as per my rules:
.AddPasswordValidator<ApplicationPasswordValidator>();

